# c# entity framework generated class sort sublist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

how can i change the default order of my entity framework generated class object

auto generated tickets class

```
public partial class tickets
{
    public tickets()
    {
        this.ticket_comments = new HashSet<ticket_comments>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ticket_comments> ticket_comments { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

}
```

auto generated ticket_comments class

```
public partial class ticket_comments
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
}
```

i want that alle ticket_comments are sorted by date by default.
as overrid is not possilbe for partial classes i've no idea how to change the default order.

thanks

Comment: This might help [link](https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-specifying-default-sort-order-in-ef-using-query-interceptors/)

Comment: An EF class is just there to connect with your database (reading and writing data + keeping track of changes). If you want ordering, or anything else that is not directly related to what I mentioned, then you should consider creating a **Model** or **ViewModel** class to tune and polish the 'raw' data into what you want it to be, or to make it behave how you want it to behave.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @PeterB.  While that interceptor looks like some fine work, all you really need is an OrderBy wherever you want a specific ordering.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you for your comment. i've already tried a simple orderby. however, this wont simple work if i've a list of tickets and all the tickets contain a list of ticket_comments which i want to sort e.g var mytickets = db.tickets.ToList(); looping through all tickets is not very nice

Comment: @PeterB thanks for your comment. i thought there is maybe a simple solution instead of creating Models as there are already auto generated classes from EF

Comment: You could always use a custom SQL statement with whatever ordering you want.  That way, it gets returned from the server already in the proper order.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I also agree with @PeterB - sorting should not be a concern of the entity. Sort the list when you use it: `foreach comment in myticket.ticket_comments.OrderBy(tc => tc.date)`